# How can I store and retrieve Gestures?

Tags: android, gestures

How can I create a gesture and store it in Android?
I want to list those gestures also.
Can anyone provide me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The Android dev [`Gestures`](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) page has a link to their [`GesturesDemos`](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/downloads/detail?name=GesturesDemos.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges) example code.  The `GesturesDemos` contains the `Gesture Builder` sample app which is used to create `Gestures`.  There are also examples that show you how to import and use these `Gestures` in your app.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

very useful 
[creating a simple-gesture-app with android](http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/)